# Unable to implement static variables in wcf C#

Tags: c#, wcf, static

Here is my problem.
I am implementing a simple client server using wcf.The server exposes a 'sum' function in which any value sent by a client is added to a global sum and this sum is returned to all clients connected to the server at the time.
This is the function

```
  public void AddMessage(int num)
    {
        sum = sum + num;
        //Go through the list of connections and call their callback funciton
        subscribers.ForEach(delegate(IMessageCallback callback)
        {
            if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Calling OnMessageAdded on callback ({0}).", callback.GetHashCode());

                callback.OnMessageAdded(sum, DateTime.Now);
            }
            else
            {
                subscribers.Remove(callback);
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the callback function that server calls

```
 public void OnMessageAdded(int sum, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sum+ ": " + timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
    }
```

There is no problem till this part.
I now tried running a client and server on a different port(8001)
The client would initially contact server listening to port 8000 and once it gets the sum,update the server listening on 8001.

Here's the code that does that.

```
  //This is the function that the SERVER will call
    public void OnMessageAdded(int sum, DateTime timestamp)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sum + ": " + timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
        WCFService.RCRServer.Sum=sum;
        Console.WriteLine("8001's sum " + WCFService.RCRServer.Sum);
    }
```

As you can see 'sum' is a static field in RCRServer.This is how it's declared.

```
        private static int sum =0;

    public static int Sum
    {
        get { return sum; }
        set { sum = value; }

    }
```

This updating also is fine.The problem starts when the connection to port 8000 is lost and i try calling the same service on port 8001.I expected that since the client keeps updating the static field for the server on port 8001,when a client calls the function on this server(8001) the old sum would be available.But it gets reset to 0 and starts the counting again.Where am I going wrong here.Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Keeping state in a service is problematic at best, your worker processes and app pool can be recycled as needed.  A much more stable option would be to store the persistent sum in a database.

Comment: Are your servers on port 8000 and 8001 separate processes ?

Comment: You will need to be careful with your variable naming, just now you have a static called "sum", but also, your functions take the parameter "sum" are you sure that you are working with the correct variable?

Comment: yes the servers on 8000 and 8001 are separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is just wrong:

```
 WCFService.RCRServer.Sum=sum;
```

as it isn't a standard WCF call but a property call. In order to link properties through WCF calls you need to explicitly mark the getter and the setter with the Operation Contract attribute but since interfaces can't be implemented by static constructs I would say what's actually being called is something else.

Try to implement a WCF method called UpdateSum(int sum) that increases the static variable and call that method.

Comment: Hi @Jorge, In that line I am in fact setting a static variable.It is not meant to be a WCF function call.the client is still connected to the server listening on 8000 when it tries to update the value of sum in the server process listening on 8001.

Comment: You're saying once you receive the SUM from the server on 8000, you update the server on 8001, I thought you intended to do that with that line, so how do you actually update the value on the second server?

Comment: WCFService.RCRServer reference is for the server listening on 8001.The updating is done with this line as you say.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to say. Are the client AND the server the SAME process? That's is, it's an application that acts both as a client and as a server?